# Javascript AJAX : node scoping

Tags: javascript, ajax, scoping

I wrote this JS code :

```
var abils = document.getElementsByName('aggiunta_abil');
for (let i = 0; i < abils.length; i++) {

  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(abils[i].parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML);

    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 || status == 200) {
      abils[i].parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }

  var url = 'my url';

  if(abils[i].value != '') url = url + 'id_abil' + '=' + abils[i].value + '&';    
    xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
}
```

My problem is that the alert stamps correclty the innerHTML of the node, but 2 lines after it says me that abils[i] is not defined. Even if I remove the if clause , keeping only the 2 instructions one after the other one , nothing changes : the alert keep working well but the `abils[i].parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = this.responseText;` no.
I also tryed with jquery for ajax , but nothing change : in the success function it says me that abils[i] is not defined.
I don't know what to do , please help me.

Comment: why are you using so many double-single quotes? `"` is not `''`...

Comment: Change `var` to `let` and put all functionality that depends on the response inside the `readystatechange` handler.

Comment: i am using double-single quotes because I am developing using SQLDeveloper, by the way i assure you that syntax is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your for loop, make a copy of “i” in first line as,
let j=i;
And then, instead of using “i”, use “j” to access the element.see if it helps

Comment: I just saw that @CertainPerformance has mentioned the same. Please use that and let us know if it works.

Comment: It actually worked !! Thank you so much !

Comment: Can you explain me why please ?

Comment: From what I understood, this behavior is because the function completes its “execution context” by the time response comes back and the variable “i” becomes length + 1 in memory. “Length + 1” is undefined. Hence we need to find a way to persist the value in memory for each loop. The keyword “let” will make copies of the variable in each “execution context “ of the function. “Execution context “ is created by the JS engine every time a function is executed.

Comment: oh , ok , i think i understood. Thank you

Comment: So is there a way to make the loop wait that the response come back ?

Comment: I don’t think we can make the loop wait because of the fact that JS engine is synchronous by nature. It executed all the code line by line. JS engine is single threaded. If that raises question in your mind about how async calls work, then just know that async calls are achieved by leveraging other components of the browser. JS engine is just one of the components in browser.

Comment: There's no need to introduce an extra variable. He can just change the `var i` to `let i`.

Comment: @JLRishe Agreed. This is much better.

Comment: mmm this is really bad , do you have any tips on how could i do the loop work ?